# Can't execute code after Thread.currentThread().join()

Tags: java

When I write `Thread.currentThread().join();` I can't execute code after that line.
If I removed it, I get error.
Is there similar of that line that let me execute the rest of my code.

Comment: We'll need to see what you've done. This question is very vague

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006829/how-start-remote-webdriver-after-regitering-a-node-in-a-hub My full code is in that post

Comment: @ManelChaabene please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Almost all of that code is irrelevant to the issue in this question (e.g. [this code](http://ideone.com/Xl4TeM) replicates the issue).

Comment: In the linked question, there seems to be an attempt to have the program wait indefinitely, but instead of using some infinite loop, it just invokes `Thread.currentThread().join()`, for which I can't for the love of me find any usefulness, unless maybe coupled with a `catch` block for `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Why would you not expect `Thread.currentThread().join()` to block until interrupted? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: @Mena I've seen a couple of questions recently, like this one, where people invoke methods on `Thread.currentThread()` that I'd never have even thought to try.

Comment: @AndyTurner weird...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.join` waits for a given thread to complete (to "die" is the expression used in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)) and resumes the current execution thereafter.

If you are joining the current thread (`Thread.currentThread()`), you're essentially waiting forever, unless an `InterruptedException` is caught and handled in a way that would make execution stop.

Note that whichever "error" you are getting in the lines following this is likely unrelated, and would caution a new question.